# XLConnect causing failures on empty cells

Tags: r, xlconnect

I've got a bunch of Excel spreadsheets from which I need to read certain cells. I've built a loop to go through all the workbooks and worksheets, but I've foregone the looping in my question below to simplify.

Not all worksheets or cells will have data populated, but if a cell is blank, XLConnect returns an empty data frame, leading to errors.

To reproduce, create an `xlsx` file in your working directory called `testFile.xlsx`. On `Sheet1`, type anything you want in cells `A1` and `B2`, then save and close the file. Then run the below code.

```
# Load packages
library(XLConnect)

# Define positions to read
positionsToRead = c('A1', 'B2')

# This will work as A1 and B2 have data
data.frame(sapply(positionsToRead, function(x) readWorksheetFromFile("testFile.xlsx",  sheet='Sheet1', region=x, header=FALSE)))

# Change positions to read
positionsToRead = c('A1', 'B2', 'C3')

# This will fail, as C3 has no data
data.frame(sapply(positionsToRead, function(x) readWorksheetFromFile("testFile.xlsx",  sheet='Sheet1', region=x, header=FALSE)))
```

The first will return:

```
  A1.Col1 B2.Col1
1   data1   data2
```

The second will return:

```
Error in data.frame(A1 = list(Col1 = "data1"), B2 = list(Col1 = "data2"),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

Is there any way to make this work?
I've searched, and found that `XLConnect` has a `SetMissing` function, but it appears to be for defining strings like `blank` to `NA`.

Comment: Any reason to be committed to `XLConnect`? Have you tried `readxl` or `xlsx`?

Comment: I'm open to alternatives. However... readxl doesn't let me read specific cells, unless I missed a function or parameter. `xlsx` results in the same error as XLConnect, from my trials. Also, I prefer XLConnect for this particular function, as it lets me specify a range in the form "E19" unlike xlsx, which would be something like `rowRange = 5:5, colRange = 19:19`. Since I'm going to be making this a function, I want the users to be able to pass the ranges to read, and XLConnect will make that easier.

Comment: Try the `autofitRow` and `autofitCol` arguments.

Comment: @joran - I can't believe I spent hours on something that turned out to be so simple. Thank you. Would you or someone else want to write that up as the answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sapply(positionsToRead, 
       function(x) readWorksheetFromFile("testFile.xlsx",  
                                         sheet='Sheet1', 
                                         region=x, 
                                         header=FALSE,
                                         autofitRow = FALSE,
                                         autofitCol = FALSE))
```